# Trouble reading from port, InputStream hangs

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to write a program that listens to port 4444 on the machine it is running on and logs all incoming data.

This is my code so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Foo {
URL url;
URLConnection connection;
InputStreamReader stream;
BufferedReader in;
String inputLine;
int test = 0;

public Foo()
{
    Connect();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Foo bridge = new Foo();
    System.out.println("made the class");
    for(;;)
    {
        System.out.println("in the loop");
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("making the try");
            if((bridge.inputLine = bridge.in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("reading the line");
                System.out.println(bridge.inputLine);
            }
        }
        /*catch(NullPointerException n)
        {
            System.out.println(bridge.test);
            bridge.test++;
        }*/
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("MAIN" + e);
        }
    }
}

public int Connect()
{       
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("starting the constructor");
        URL url = new URL("http", "192.168.0.104", 4444, "");
        System.out.println("url ready");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        System.out.println("connection ready");
        //connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("stream ready");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(stream);
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        System.out.println("bufferReader ready");

        return 0;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("CON" + e);
    }
    return 1;
}
}
```

When I run it I get this as output.

```
D:\temp_104\foo>java -cp . foo
starting the constructor
url ready
connection ready
```

Every single time it hangs when it tries to create an input stream. 
I have tested it with hyperterminal and the server is outputting messages and can be connected to on port 4444. I am running java 1.5.0_15 and cannot update.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: can you run jstack on the process and post where it is hung?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with jstack, how would I run it on the program ?

Comment: it is part of the jdk.  'jstack [PID]' will dump the traces.  or if you are running this in the debugger you can look at the traces there.  or you could try creating your input stream (connection.getInputStream()) first to see if it is hanging there.

Comment: I do create the input stream first and it is hanging there. The cmd window will not allow me to type once the program hangs and if I open another cmd screen it says jstack is unreconised.

Comment: looks like jstack is not in 1.5.0..., so in, InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());, move connection.getInputStream() out and see if that method is hanging or the reader constructor.  I suspect the former.

Comment: it is connection.getInputStream() that is hanging like you thought, do yo have a solution for that ?

Comment: please look at http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection if you look at the server with a browser do you get anything? is it really serving up the http protocol?  the httpurlconnection sends a http GET on inputstream

Comment: the server sends out a string with an STX and ETX over a client socket on port 4444. All the tutorials said to use httpurlconnection, what should I be using instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was scope. The buffered reader was being initialised fine in the function but once back in the main it was null.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading lines with an BufferedReader.  Is the server writing newlines at the end of each message?

Comment: you meant to say BufferedReader? :)

Comment: I don't see how that matters the program crashes in the inputstreams constructor it never reads anything.

Comment: @Skeith, if the program is crashing, then please post the stack trace

Comment: there is no stack trace it just hangs on the inputstream call.